# 3D model rotation in react three fiber

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm new here and have question related to 3D model rotation in react three fiber.
here is the link for codesend: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cool-bogdan-y5c2ny
if someone knows how to rotate the model I will be very thankful. if there is too much job and require compensation pleas give me quote. Thank you

rotes for the sendcode are: src / canvas / shirt where the model is uploaded;
src / canvas / index where the main canvas element is loaded and
src / canvas / CameraRig where easing dumpE setting position but can not set rotation [text](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cool-bogdan-y5c2ny)